# OLE connection access mdb to personal geodatabase

Tags: python, vba, ms-access, arcgis, ole

Please HELP!
I am very new in Python.And I guess I need to use lots of Python here.

I have MS Access 2003-2007 database (mdb format) and personal geodatabase (mdb). I created a tool in Access that imports data from personal geodatabase to access mdb, checks it and updates changes.

Now I am working on implementing backwards functionality (transfer data from access mdb to personal geodatabase). 
For now, I can implement that manually using OLE connection.

How I do it:

1. in ArcCatalog create OLE connection,
2. Connect to my access database backend,
3. Choose a Table I want to use from this access database backend,
4. Open ArcMap, add Feature class from personal geodatabase to the map,
5. Perform join of Feature class and Table,
6. Then using Field calculator update all necessary fields,

For now in my vision I can create custom tool for join Feature class and Table.

Do you have any suggestions how I can automate this process, at least half of this process.

Thanks you!

Here is a code to join Table to Feature Class

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = 1
env.workspace = r"D:\Working\Tools\ToolShare\Scripts"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Crossings", "tempLayer")
arcpy.AddJoin_management("tempLayer", "UNIQUE_NAME", "tblCrossings", "UNIQUE_NAM")
```

Comment: Since you have ArcMap, you also have access to ArcPy functions. Have you put any portion of this into a Python script so far?

Comment: I am trying to have a code for join Table to Feature class. It doesn't show any errors, but also I don't see any new fields in Feature class. Here is my code `import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = 1
env.workspace = r"D:\Working\Tools\ToolShare\Scripts"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Crossings", "tempLayer")
arcpy.AddJoin_management("tempLayer", "UNIQUE_NAME", "tblCrossings", "UNIQUE_NAM")`

Comment: Please edit that into the question so it is easier to read :)

Comment: I added the code to the question

Comment: You might want to try StackGIS (e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34981/getting-values-from-attribute-table-and-inserting-another-table-using-arcpy)